# Next.js Handling User Logged In Status

Tags: express, oauth-2.0, next.js, next-auth

I'm using next-iron-session in my next.js project with discord oauth2.

My Session Code:

```
import {
    GetServerSidePropsContext,
    NextApiRequest,
    NextApiResponse,
} from "next";
import { withIronSession, Session } from "next-iron-session";



export type NextIronRequest = NextApiRequest & { session: Session };
export type NextIronHandler = (
    req: NextIronRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse
) => void | Promise<void>;

export type NextRoute = (
    ctx: GetServerSidePropsContext & { req: { session: Session } },
    redirect: string
) => any;

export function withSession(handler: NextIronHandler | NextRoute) {
    return withIronSession(handler, {
        password: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET as string,
        cookieName: "session",
        ttl: 15 * 24 * 3600,
        cookieOptions: {
            secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
            sameSite: "strict",
            httpOnly: true,
        },
    });
}
```

Auth Handler Code:

```
import next, { GetServerSidePropsContext } from 'next'
import { withSession } from './session'

export const withAuth = (gssp: any) => {
    return async (context: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
        const { req } = context
        const user = req.session.user

        if (!user) {
            return {
                redirect: {
                    destination: '/api/auth/login',
                    statusCode: 302,
                },
            }
        } 

        return await gssp(context)
    }
}

export const withAuthSsr = (handler: any) => withSession(withAuth(handler))
```

Dashboard Code:

```
import { GetServerSideProps, NextApiRequest } from "next";
import Head from "next/head";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import { NextIronRequest } from "../util/session";
import { User, UserData } from "src/types";
import { developerRoute } from "src/util/redirects";
import { withSession } from "src/util/session";
import Router from "next/router";
import { redirect } from "next/dist/server/api-utils";
import { withAuthSsr } from '../util/AuthHandler'

interface Props {
  user?: User;
}


export default function Dashboard(req: NextIronRequest) {
  function Icon(icon: string) {
    console.log(icon)
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>{req.user.user.username} | Dashboard</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href={req.user.avatar} />
      </Head>
      <body>
        {
          req.user.guilds.map((guild: any) => {
            return (
              <>
                <div className="p-10 items-center justify-center flex flex-center grid grid-cols-2 grid-flow-row sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-3 gap-5">
                  <div className="rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg">
                    <img className="w-full" src={Icon(guild.icon)} alt="Guild Icon" />
                    <div className="px-6 py-4">
                      <div className="font-bold text-center text-xl mb-2">{guild.name}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="px-6 pt-4 pb-2 items-center content-center justify-center">
                      <a href="#_" className="relative inline-flex items-center justify-center p-4 px-6 py-3 overflow-hidden font-medium text-indigo-600 transition duration-300 ease-out border-2 border-purple-500 rounded-full shadow-md group">
                        <span className="absolute inset-0 flex items-center justify-center w-full h-full text-white duration-300 -translate-x-full bg-purple-500 group-hover:translate-x-0 ease">
                          <svg className="w-6 h-6" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M14 5l7 7m0 0l-7 7m7-7H3"></path></svg>
                        </span>
                        <span className="absolute flex items-center justify-center w-full h-full text-purple-500 transition-all duration-300 transform group-hover:translate-x-full ease">Manage Settings</span>
                        <span className="relative invisible">Manage Settings</span>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </>
            )
          })
        }
      </body>
    </>
  )
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = withSession(withAuthSsr(developerRoute))
```

What's happening now is, if the user is even loggedIn it will redirect for login again, How do i fix that?

What did i do wrong? If the user isn't logged he/she gets redirected.

Next.js Version: 12.0.7
Next-Iron-Session Version: 4.2.0

Comment: You use `sameSite: strict` cookies for sessions. Do your backend and frontend operate on the same domain? Are there any errors in the browser's console? Very often the browser will tell you that it is dropping a cookie for some reason.

Comment: Yes, I'm on localhost currently.

Comment: Also, What you said is already present. Have a look on the session code

Comment: Probably not related to the issue, but you don't need to wrap `withAuthSsr` with `withSession` if you're already doing so inside `withAuthSsr`.